# Insert data in database using form

Tags: database, forms, table

I am writing a simple plugin that create a table with name "newsletter" in database and  provide a shortcode to put a registration form in pages.
the form contain "name" and "email".
i have problem with inserting the form data(name+email) in database.
i wrote this:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
function insertuser(){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
$wpdb->insert($table_name, array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email) ); 
}
?>
```

but id does not work. what should i do to get data from form and insert into table?

Comment: Have you added any prefix to newsletter table?

Comment: adding prefix where exactly?  the table in database have prefix

Comment: before table name because you have used this $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter"; in your code which adds wordpress prefix before the table name newsletter so if you have not added any prefix to table name than only use table name like this $table_name = "newsletter";

Comment: The two variables `name` and `email` are **unknown** inside the function. You have to either define them inside the function, or if they are needed elsewhere, declare them `global` (both _outside_ and _inside_ the function).

Comment: @VinodDalvi : i added th eprefix for table in database.

Comment: i defined the name and email inside function but nothing happen.

Comment: What is the prefix you have added to the table? tell me the full table name with prefix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two variables `$name` and `$email` are unknown inside the function. You have to make them globally available inside it by changing `global $wpdb` into `global $wpdb, $name, $email`:

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

/**
 * After t f's comment about putting global before the variable.
 * Not necessary (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
 */
global $name = $_POST['name'];
global $email = $_POST['email'];

function insertuser(){
  global $wpdb, $name, $email;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
  $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email) ); 
}

insertuser();
```

Or, you can put the variables in the function's arguments:

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email']

function insertuser( $name, $email ) {
  global $wpdb;

  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'newsletter';
  $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email
  ) );
}

insertuser( $name, $email );
```

Or, without function:

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

global $wpdb;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email
) );
```

Comment: That's what I wrote. ;) I'm still having issues with when to write a comment and when it's enough for an answer. ;) The variables still have to be declared `global` _outside_ the function, though.

Comment: Haha, yes I saw your comment after I posted my answer :-) my rule of commenting/answering is, if OP has to change more than one rule in the code, always answer ;-) I'll add `global` to the variables `$name` and `$email`

Comment: Ah, okay, you seem to be right with the scope (because in this case, _outside_ the function **is** the global scope, and not a class). However, if you declare the variables global (what you decided to do now), you first have to declare, and then (in the next line, or after a semicolon) set a value.

Comment: when user click on submit form the form's action refer to an file call :regiostration-form.php in this file i have this code now:

`<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

function insertuser(){
  global $wpdb, $name, $email;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
  $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email) ); 
}
?> `

but it does not work again. anything wrong?

Comment: You do call the `insertuser()` function after you declare the function?

Comment: @MikeMadern  do i have to write: 'insertuser()' after function?

Comment: defining a function doesn't automatically executes it. You have to call the function in order to execute. See the code in my answer ;-)

Comment: i used your code but i got two errors: Notice: `Trying to get property of non-object in line 8` and `Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in line 9`

Comment: It isn't a file loaded by WordPress right? `require` the `wp-load.php` file on top of your script to load the WordPress library.

Comment: i used this code and worked fine: `<?php
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "newsletter";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'name' => $name, 'email' => $email ) );
?>
`  Thanks all guys specially Mike Madern

Comment: yes, please update the answer with complete answer then i will accept it. Sincererly

Comment: I updated my answer for you ;)