# What is the best practice to initialise $wpdb by loading wp-load.php?

Tags: wpdb, wp-load.php

Why do users with high reputations suggest loading `wp-load.php` with a full path?

My question is simple and was originally intended as an answer to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90836/insert-data-in-database-using-form) question. However I do not have a high enough reputation to answer or comment to that question. Rant over - sorry.

Surely loading `wp-load.php` with a hard coded path is bad practice. If the installation moves or your plugin is loaded into an installation where `wp-load.php` is in a different location, it will fail.

Browsing around I have found a few alternatives and others are welcome. The best I can tell is using the absolute path variable provided by WordPress.

```
<?php
   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php' );
   global $wpdb;
?>
```

Personally I have had no trouble initializing the `$wpdb` object, but I am sure this time will come. Nonetheless I found the linked question above as the top answer from Google and thought I should add in something else to help the ol' community.

Comment: I'd probably answer that it's best practice to entirely avoid having to include `wp-load.php`, but the context of your code isn't clear.

Comment: `ABSPATH` defined by WordPress is not available until you load `wp-load.php`, `require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php' );` won't work.

Comment: Thanks guys for replying.
@Milo: I agree completely. As mentioned in my question, this was originally intended as a response to another question where loading wp-load.php was given as an answer.